# Mapping array to dictionary doesn't work for first object

Tags: javascript

I have a small snippet of code here, I'm trying to create a map using one of the property of the object that is being mapped. Here is the code :

```
var operators = [
    { priority: 1, symbol: '-'},
    { priority: 1, symbol: '+'},
    { priority: 2, symbol: '*'}
];

var foo = operators.reduce(function(map,obj) {
    map[obj.symbol] = obj;
    return map;
});

console.log(foo);
```

The output of this code is :

```
{ priority: 1,
  symbol: '-',
  '+': { priority: 1, symbol: '+' },
  '*': { priority: 2, symbol: '*' } }
```

As you notice, the first object isn't correctly mapped. I've tried changing the order to see if I had a typo in my code but the problem persists.

What is wrong?

Comment: You need to pass an initial empty object to `reduce`.

Comment: what is the outcome you are expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```js
var operators = [
    { priority: 1, symbol: '-'},
    { priority: 1, symbol: '+'},
    { priority: 2, symbol: '*'}
];

var foo = operators.reduce(function(map,obj) {
    map[obj.symbol] = obj;
    return map;
}, {}); // pass in initial empty map object

console.log(foo);
```

Read the documentation of `reduce` for the [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters).

---

If you don't pass in an initial value then `reduce` considers the first element of the array as the initial value. Hence, it adds two new properties to the object `{ priority: 1, symbol: '-'}`.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the use of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a proper initial value, you could take ES6 and map new objects and with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with a [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for a new object.

```js
var operators = [{ priority: 1, symbol: '-'}, { priority: 1, symbol: '+'}, { priority: 2, symbol: '*'}],
    object = Object.assign(...operators.map(o => ({ [o.symbol]: o})));

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```